# best way to show and hide list item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two list items, and i have to show the first item if some condition is met, otherwise i will show the second one.

for example

```
<li class="login" style="display:block"> 
    <a href="#" id="sign_up_link" data-modal="#create-account-modal" data-  reveal-id="create-account-modal"></a>
</li>

<li class="login" style="display:none"> 
  <a class="btn" href="#" id="sign_up_link" data-modal="#create-account-modal" data-reveal-id="create-account-modal"></a>
</li>
```

I cannot change id of the list item. I have two option

1. I can add one more class in list item to differentiate which to show
   and which to hide.
2. or i can put each list item in separate div with some id and based
   on that div's id i can show or hide.

which one is good 1) or 2)??

Is there any best option??

Comment: you should most definitely change a class on the list items to show or hide them. why do you have the same id on both `<a>` tags?

Comment: You have two anchors with the same `id` attribute. Even hiding/showing them, they're not gonna work as expected.

Comment: I had only one list item with an anchor tag with text link, now i need to replace the link by a button. I had to place the same id otherwise other test cases will start fail.

Comment: ...... *i have to show the first item if some condition is met* .... what triggers that condition?

Comment: That is an optimizely variable. if that true i will show link otherwise button.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#submit').click(function() {
  $(this).prev('#hideme').toggle();


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type='button' id='hideme' value='hide me'>
  <input type='button' id='submit' value='submit'>
</div>
```

> Description: Display or hide the matched elements.

Documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

You can use `.toggle()` to hide/show element by using id as selector make sure you use unique id at all times

```js
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('#hideme').toggle();


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="hideme">
    <a href="#" id="">hide me</a>
  </li>

  <li id="clickme" >
    <a class="btn" href="#" id="">click me</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hide/show li you should have unique id as always and use proper selector to select the li you want to show or hide